# object declaration and definition in c++

Tags: c++, syntax, dynamic-allocation, new-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

I saw someone uses the constructor like this:

```
class Foo
{
  public: Foo();
};

int main(){
  Foo *f= new Foo;
}
```

what is the difference between `Foo *f= new Foo;` and `Foo *f= new Foo();`  ?

Comment: Is this really C++? Both won't compile (both returns `Foo*`).

Comment: @KennyTM, edited the post with removing compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the code you give will not compile. You need to have

`Foo* f = new Foo()`

Notice the asterisk.

Otherwise the two calls have the same result for non-primitive types. I have worked in companies where the () syntax is enforced by the styleguide and for a good reason: for primitive types there can be a difference:

```
int* p = new p;
cout << *p << endl; // the value is arbitrary i.e. behavior is undefined.
int* q = new int();
cout << *q << endl; // outputs 0.
```

It may be obvious here but imagine that Foo is a typedef for instance. So my advice is: always use the Foo() syntax.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no difference** between those two forms of initializations. Both will call the default constructor, given that the constructor is `public`.

Comment: There is a difference for built-ins.

Comment: @sbi: i wasn't talking about built ins. may be i should be more elaborate.

Comment: @iammilind: how is having bold text significantly better?

Comment: @sehe, bold text will give the heart of the answer in brief. Those who are further interested can read it in detail. Nothing much :)

Comment: @Donotalo: Yes, I think this would help.

Answer (score 1):

Ỳour example probably even won't compile, you need to declare a pointer

```
 Foo *f = new Foo;
```

and there is no difference in typing `new Foo` or `new Foo()` since both run the constructor with no arguments.